# can farming simulator 2013 be run on macbook air, both 11 inch and 13 inch?

Tags: macos

I would like to ask if the game farming simulator 2013 can be run in both the mac book air 11 inch and 13 inch? This is because i am intending to get a mac book air next year, and the game in question.

Answer (score 1):

I would think it should run fine on either...  the game has very low system requirements.   You can view the requirements here:

**Official WebSite**

http://www.farming-simulator.com/about.php?lang=en